# get and display data in MVC 3 using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one view page in MVC named as ‘Index’. There are 3 main controls in that view page. For better understanding, take below example as reference.
1.    One Dropdown ‘Customer’
2.    One Dropdown ‘Project’ (that depends on ‘Customer’)
3.    List of Task (that depends on ‘Project’).

Currently first user needs to select ‘Customer’. So based on customer ‘Project’ dropdown data will be fetched from post method of Index and bind that ‘Project’ dropdown. After selecting ‘Project’, List of task will be fetch from post method of Index and bind those tasks. So every time page is loaded again.I want to do it by Ajax form submit.

My problem – those 3 controls are in one view page so I want to return page view using Ajax without using Partial View. Is this possible? If yes then how? Or any other solution so that I am able to display data without reload whole page again.

If u can give me example of such scenario then it will be good.

Comment: This has been asked many times before: [Cascading dropdown using asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942909/cascading-dropdown-using-asp-net-mvc) is one of them. Google for "cascading dropdowns" and you'll find a [guide by Stephen Walter](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx) that might help you further.